# Audio sharpening

Tags: fft, audio

I'm working on a project where the purpose is to enhance FFT peaks in a signal (musical instruments), by other words, reduce non-harmonic components and enhance the identified FFT peaks. So far I'm doing the following:

1. I'm analysing the file on a frame basis and
2. for each frame, I calculate an AR(8) model,
3. then reduce the bandwidth for each peak and
4. apply this as a filter to the frame,
5. combine everything using PSOLA

The results are good but they could be better. Any ideas for a different approach?

Comment: wanna do it with a time-domain approach, rather than FFT?

Comment: or use a frequency domain that is dedicatedly combining harmonics into a single number?